# Power BI : Comparing Months from 2 years

Tags: powerbi-desktop, linechart

[actual result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jDUFB.png)

I would like to have January after December as I would like to compare 2 measures month by month

I tried to sort year by year or add a different hierarchy but it didn't work

The main problem is that data are from 3 differents years (2022,2023 and 2024)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.